# How to open vlc player from browser?

Tags: javascript, html, vlc

How to open VLC player from desktop browser ?

i tried using
`<a href="vlc://https://mystreamurl">open vlc</a>` but this one only work in android devices

Comment: Why do you expect that every user has VLC installed and integrated into their browser?

Comment: Yep, this would require that every user of the site had VLC installed and that their system configured to open `vlc:` links in VLC

Answer (score -2):

It would only work if the person has installed a VlC player installed in their desktop.

Comment: please do not post answers like these!